# How can I get the number of lines when I use \fillwithlines in exam class?

Tags: exam

I use `exam package` with the command `\fillwithlines{1.25 in}`. Now I want to get the number of lines are 3, 4, ...
I think, I use
\linefillheight{.35in} * the number of lines. But I can't the result. In this code, I get three lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\setlength\linefillthickness{0.6pt}
\setlength\linefillheight{.35in}
\begin{document}
\fillwithlines{1.25 in}
\end{document}
```

How can I get number of lines when I use \fillwithlines in exam class?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\def\numlines#1{
    \ifdim\dimexpr#1/\linefillheight*\linefillheight\relax<#1\relax
        \the\numexpr\dimexpr#1\relax/\linefillheight\relax
    \else
        \the\numexpr\dimexpr#1\relax/\linefillheight-1\relax
    \fi
}
```

There's some rounding issue when you just divide that sometimes causes the answer to be one too high. This code checks that this rounding problem has not occurred by checking that the dimension you give divided by and multiplied by the same thing is less than what you started with (we want to round down). If not, it subtracts one from the result. Note also that you need to wrap dimension expressions like `1in` inside of a `\numexpr` with `\dimexpr` or else the `\numexpr` will stop parsing when it sees the dimension.

I'm not sure how you want this to be output. The way I have written it, it just writes it to the output, but you could easily modify this to store the result somewhere or something. Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
\def\numlines#1{
    \ifdim\dimexpr#1/\linefillheight*\linefillheight\relax<#1\relax
        \the\numexpr\dimexpr#1\relax/\linefillheight\relax
    \else
        \the\numexpr\dimexpr#1\relax/\linefillheight-1\relax
    \fi
}


\numlines{0.6in}:
\fillwithlines{0.6in}

\numlines{1.2in}:
\fillwithlines{1.2in}

\numlines{1.6in}:
\fillwithlines{1.6in}

\numlines{2in}:
\fillwithlines{2in}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you write a simple command? For example, \numlines{2}, OP get two lines?

Comment: I thought he was asking for a command that takes a length and outputs the number of lines that `\fillwithlines{<length>}` will generate. I guess I misunderstood his question. If you want to get a certain number of lines, all you have to do is say, e.g., `\fillwithlines{2\linefillheight}` to get two lines.